# Filter out similar data SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter

I am using `SQL Server 2008` and `navicat`. I need to filter search results in the next way:

```
1. Data -  Id
2. 24   -   1
3. 24   -   3
4. 50   -   5
5. 50   -   8
```

I need to leave only one data with MAX id value (DISTINCT inside query doesn't work because the data I'm looking is not unique), so result should be:

```
1. Data -  Id
3. 24   -   3
5. 50      8
```

All the rest similar data values should be filtered out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Data,Max(ID) From tablename group by Data
```

Comment: Sure, i just waited for 5 minutes to allow it